# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome software not listing my software

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

I have installed my own software on Ubuntu 16.04. But it is not getting listed 
in Ubuntu 16.04  Gnome software center. Please help me what should I do so that it gets listed in Gnome software center.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you install your software ?

Comment: I installed using two methods i. e. Using  download manager as well as with the debian package of the software.  But in both ways the software did not get listed.